# How to save image from Clipboard vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

clipboard to save Image as PNG or JPG

```
If singleline.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
Dim shp4 As InlineShape
Dim image As Object
Set shp4 = singleline.Range.InlineShapes(1)
shp4.Select
Selection.Copy
image = Clipboard.GetImage
image.Save ("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
End If
```

Here how to save image to path .  here asking Object Missing

Comment: Cross-posted at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-vba-dev.html, where the O.P. again did not mention what application they are using.

Comment: Based on the tags, it looks to me like the OP is using MS-Word

Comment: Save the Word file, then rename it to ZIP, then you can open the ZIP and find the JPG files right there. I was unable to find an alternative.